# Mac M1 - ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gevent==21.8.0

Tags: python, installation, pip, apple-m1, gevent

Trying to install gevent in virtual env from a requirements.txt using pip-sync but getting this error.

```
Collecting gevent==21.8.0
  Using cached gevent-21.8.0.tar.gz (6.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gevent==21.8.0 (from versions: 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.10.0, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.13.4, 0.13.5, 0.13.6, 0.13.7, 0.13.8, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1a1, 1.1a2, 1.1b1, 1.1b2, 1.1b3, 1.1b4, 1.1b5, 1.1b6, 1.1rc1, 1.1rc2, 1.1rc3, 1.1rc4, 1.1rc5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2a1, 1.2a2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3a1, 1.3a2, 1.3b1, 1.3b2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.2.post0, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4.0, 1.5a1, 1.5a2, 1.5a3, 1.5a4, 1.5.0, 20.4.0, 20.5.0, 20.5.1, 20.5.2, 20.6.0, 20.6.1, 20.6.2, 20.9.0, 20.12.0, 20.12.1, 21.1.0, 21.1.1, 21.1.2, 21.8.0, 21.12.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gevent==21.8.0
```

Tried with:

- pip/python version: 21.3.1/3.6.15, 22.2.2/3.8.13
- Directly installing with `pip install gevent==21.8.0`

I suspect it has to do with the M1 chip as others not on the M1 were able to install with no issues.

I also don't get why the error states it can't find version 21.8.0 when that version is listed in the searched list within the ( ).

Comment: Were u able to resolve this?

Comment: @jefe23984 Yes, not sure what these commands do so use with caution but I created a new Python 3.9 virtual environment and then did
' pip install --upgrade pip-tools'
'pip-sync [requirements.txt path]'
and then there was a separate issue with pynacl which was solved with 
'arch -arm64 pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pynacl'